# Adding inputted data from a html form to a mysql database, simply

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says, I'm kinda newish to php and am after a simple and easy way to add the inputted data from the html form into my database, I use mysql, not mysqli, thank you. Sorry if this question has already been asked*

EDIT: 
My html code for the form.

I used paste bin due to the weirdness of stack overflow.

http://pastebin.com/GKF53K3X

Comment: At least provide your html code

Comment: sorry my bad, will do!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this PHP MySQL tutorial

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html

```
 //uploader.php

    mysql_connect("dbhost","username","password");//database connection
    mysql_select_db("yourdatabase");

    if(isset($_POST)){

    extract($_POST) ;
    //db insertion
    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable
                (`name`, `dev`,`size`,`email`,`link`)
                VALUES
                ('$name', '$dev','$size','$email','$link')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);    //order executes
    if($result){
        echo("<br>Data inserted successfully");
    } else{
        echo("<br>Some error occured");
    }

    }
```